RewriteRule in .htaccess to Load Files from Subfolders Without Revealing Subfolder Name
Problem Description:
I'm encountering difficulty configuring a RewriteRule in my .htaccess file to internally load files from subfolders within a specific directory without revealing the subfolder name in the URL. Despite setting up the RewriteRule, accessing URLs like http://localhost/ravenpeak/forum/signup leads to a 404 error instead of loading the intended content.
Problem Details:
Utilizing XAMPP on a MacBook, the project directory structure is organized as follows:

The objective is to configure the RewriteRule within the .htaccess file to internally load content from files within subfolders of the \Forum directory without disclosing the subfolder name in the URL.
What I Tried:
# Enable the rewrite engine to process rewrite rules
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Ravenpeak/

# Remove extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Redirect from extensions to non-extensions
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# Create Error Pages 
ErrorDocument 404 /Ravenpeak/Errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /Ravenpeak/Errors/403.html
ErrorDocument 500 /Ravenpeak/Errors/500.html

# HIDE SUBFOLDER NAMES
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ /ravenpeak/forum/(access|users)/$1 [NC,L]

Expected Outcome:
Upon accessing a URL like http://localhost/ravenpeak/forum/signup, the content corresponding to signup.php within the \Forum\Access directory should be loaded internally without displaying the subfolder name in the URL.

RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ /ravenpeak/forum/(access|users)/$1 [NC,L] - you can't use alternation in the substitution URL, that makes no sense. Based on what should the server decide here, whether to pick access or users? This will not get interpreted as a regex alternation in this position to begin with, you are rewriting to a URL literally containing .../(access|users)/... here.
